# XAML databinding to regular property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am currently experimenting with data binding in WPF/XAML. I have written a camera control that binds to the TransformProperty of a PerspectiveCamera in XAML like this:

```
<PerspectiveCamera FieldOfView="60" UpDirection="0,1,0" Transform="{Binding
 CameraControlVM.CamControl.Transform}"/>
```

The CameraControlVM is just my ViewModel class. The CamControl has a regular .Net property Transform which is used as binding source here.

```
public class CameraControl 
{
    public Transform3D Transform { get; set; }
...
}
```

So Everything works fine, but actually I am wondering *why*?! When the transform of my camera control changes, the transform of the bound perspective camera changes as well. In this situation I have bound a target (PerspectiveCamera.Transform) which is a DependencyProperty to a regular property (Transform) as a source. I have not implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface on my CameraControl, so in terms of databinding I expect only the camera control transform should be informed about changes of the actual camera transform and not the other way round. Am I missing something here or confusing the databinding rules?

**To make the question more clear:** In my setup a regular property seems to inform a DependencyProperty when it is changing WITHOUT using INotifyPropertyChanged and I thought this is not possible in data binding, is it?
Maybe it has something to do with Transform3D deriving from Animatable in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to clear the confusion

The `Transform` is a normal property in `CameraControl` class so changing the value of the property will not fire any notification and hence UI will not be able to respond

on the other hand type of Transform is `Transform3D` which is derived from `DependencyObject` and hence is capable of notifying any property change within the instance.

So in essence during runtime if you change the value of Transform property that will not reflect to UI

eg.

```
cam.Transform = new Transform3D();
```

where as if you modify the properties of the Transform3D instance that will be reflected to UI

eg.

```
cam.Transform.Value = new Matrix3D();
```

I hope I am able to clear the confusion.

Comment: Thx. thats the point. I am not actually changing the Transform property by calling its setter or anything but I am changing its contents (the matrix) and that is reflected to UI.

Answer (score 0):

WPF for some properties has a TwoWay as a default binding mode (like Text property in TextBox control ) so if you want to solve your issue you can try `Mode=OneWay` like the following:

```
<PerspectiveCamera FieldOfView="60" UpDirection="0,1,0" Transform="{Binding
     CameraControlVM.CamControl.Transform, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. It works fine for me but I don't understand why, because in my setup a regular property seems to inform a DependencyProperty when it is changing WITHOUT using INotifyPropertyChanged and I thought this is not possible in data binding?!

Comment: If I put the Binding to OneWay everything still works fine, but I still do not understand why. See the Edit above in my question pls. Thx.