# Binding to Transform3dGroup in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have an already properly working data binding (WPF, C#, Net4.5) between an element of my view (a PerspectiveCamera as target) and a `Transform3DGroup allTransform {get; set;}` regular .Net property as source which is part of my viewmodel. I need to know why/how it is actually working.

The Transform3DGroup has a TranslateTransform3D object in his list of children. I am changing the Offset Properties of this TranslateTransform within my viewmodel:

```
// create my transform group
this.allTransforms = new Transform3DGroup();    
this.translateToPos = new TranslateTransform3D();
allTransforms.Children.Add(translateToPos);     

...
// updating the translation while rendering is done like this. 
// X, Y, Z are just some properties of this class
this.translateToPos.OffsetX = this.X;   
this.translateToPos.OffsetY = this.Y;
this.translateToPos.OffsetZ = this.Z;
```

So the camera bound to this transform group actually reacts properly (with a translation). In my understanding of data binding a DependencyProperty is capable of informing a bound property of any changes, but my Transform3DGroup isn't a DependencyProperty, so how does it work? The children collection of Transform3DGroup IS a DependencyProperty but I am not *changing the collection*, but only updating one of its members. The OffsetX, OffsetY, OffsetZ properties in TranslateTransform3D actually are DependencyProperty. So how is their change notification propagated to the owning TransformGroup3D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer, let me explain it

you are not changing the value of the property allTransforms which is a normal property but you are manipulating the values of one of it's child transform property so how does changed reach to the bound camera?

some facts

- Transform3DGroup is a DependencyObject
- property Children in Transform3DGroup is of type Transform3DCollection which is DependencyObject
- and the actual child TranslateTransform3D is also DependencyObject

all of the above are capable of notifying to its parent

so when ever you modify translateToPos which is TranslateTransform3D

- it notifies the change to its parent which is Transform3DCollection
- Transform3DCollection notify its parent which is in Transform3DGroup
- Transform3DGroup notify the camera which is bound to it.
- camera receives the latest computed value from Transform3DGroup and reacts accordingly.

I hope I am able to explain it

Comment: Thx again: This is closely related to my former question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329448/xaml-databinding-to-regular-property but now I see the details.

Comment: In detail it actually is based on class Freezable. Transform3D is derived from Freezable, which itself is derived from DependencyObject but changes the default notification behaviour. Freezable objects always send change notification when a sub-property has changed. So if the actual Matrix3D of a Transform3D is changed, the change propagates up the hierarchy and the top level Freezable sends the last change notification to everyone who is binding to it.